# I pressed something, and my object went curved

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

I was modeling an object, using the Maya keyboard layout, and as I was pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to move the camera, my finger slipped, and the object went... strange. I've observed this effect before, but I can't remember what it's called or how to (un)do it. The shape deformed, rounded off, and really annoying. What did I do, and how can I fix this?

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely added a *sub-surface* modifier on your object. You can do this by pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, adding a sub-division surface with the respective amount of divisions.

Because you were pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> before it happened, your finger probably landed on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when it slipped.

In your second screenshot, you do not have your object selected, so the modifier would not display. in the *modifiers* panel

You can remove it by going to the *modifiers* panel and deleting the modifier.
[image]

Comment: And so I did. Thank you so much! It's fixed now!